# Есть меню в футере, необходимо, при нажатии на ссылку, чтобы был переход на другую страницу и там нажатие на кнопку, чтобы открывалось подменю

Tags: jquery

[image: При нажатии на кпопку введение][image: При нажатии на кнопку преимущества[![][1]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWyNT.jpg)[[image: Footer with link]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsySh.jpg)
Footer

```
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-7 col-lg-4">
                            <div class="footer-up_item footer-up_item_first">
                                <div class="footer-up_caption">
                                    О компании
                                </div>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="about.html">Введение, миссия и ценности</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="about.html">Преимущества</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="about.html">Клиенты</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="about.html">Партнеры</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="about.html">Контакты</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Меню на странице about

```
                     <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
                        <ul class="about__nav_menu tabs_menu" >
                            <li class="about__nav_menu-item">
                                <a href="#">Введение</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="about__nav_menu-item  about__nav_menu-start" id="perh">
                                <a href="#">Преимущества</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="about__nav_menu-item" >
                                <a href="#">Клиенты</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="about__nav_menu-item" >
                                <a href="#">Партнеры</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="about__nav_menu-item" >
                                <a href="#">Контакты</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

код

```
        $('.about__nav_menu-item:nth-child(1)').click(function () {
        $('.about__nav_menu-item').removeClass('about__nav_menu-start');
        $('.about__nav_menu-item:nth-child(1)').addClass('about__nav_menu-start');
        $('.about__adv_item').addClass('d-none');
        $('.about__adv_item:nth-child(1)').removeClass('d-none');
        });

        $('.about__nav_menu-item:nth-child(2)').click(function () {
        $('.about__nav_menu-item').removeClass('about__nav_menu-start');
        $('.about__nav_menu-item:nth-child(2)').addClass('about__nav_menu-start');
        $('.about__adv_item').addClass('d-none');
        $('.about__adv_item:nth-child(2)').removeClass('d-none');
        });

        $('.about__nav_menu-item:nth-child(3)').click(function () {
        $('.about__nav_menu-item').removeClass('about__nav_menu-start');
        $('.about__nav_menu-item:nth-child(3)').addClass('about__nav_menu-start');
        $('.about__adv_item').addClass('d-none');
        $('.about__adv_item:nth-child(3)').removeClass('d-none');
        });

        $('.about__nav_menu-item:nth-child(4)').click(function () {
        $('.about__nav_menu-item').removeClass('about__nav_menu-start');
        $('.about__nav_menu-item:nth-child(4)').addClass('about__nav_menu-start');
        $('.about__adv_item').addClass('d-none');
        $('.about__adv_item:nth-child(4)').removeClass('d-none');
        });

        $('.about__nav_menu-item:nth-child(5)').click(function () {
        $('.about__nav_menu-item').removeClass('about__nav_menu-start');
        $('.about__nav_menu-item:nth-child(5)').addClass('about__nav_menu-start');
        $('.about__adv_item').addClass('d-none');
        $('.about__adv_item:nth-child(5)').removeClass('d-none');
        });
```

Comment: Возможно, так будет понятнее: нажимаешь на footer-up_caption a:nth-child(1)(нажатие должно быть со страниц index.html или services.html, должен совершиться переход на страницу about.html и эмитировать клик на .about__nav_menu-item:nth-child(1)

Comment: Вопрос решился с помощью исспользования WordPress, там создаешь структуру и он сам генерирует ссылка на каждую эту страницу. Необходимо только немного знания php